# JSON data in Kivy app not allowing any scrolling

Tags: python, kivy

I have a Kivy app with a page that loads some json data, the data seems to be larger than the screen size, and I cant get it to start at the top and allow for scroll

So I'm looking for the page to load the data to start at the top and be scrollable and allow the bac button to be at the bottom of the page

I have also tried to add ScrollView but that doesn't seem to work too well.

So my KV file is:

```
<ContentScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10

        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
        Label:
            id: content_label
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            font_size: '16'
            text_size: self.width, None
        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            size_hint:(None, None)
            size:(86, 34)
            background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
            font_size:'16'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'main_screen'
                app.refresh_button_text(self)
                app.clear_input()
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
```

My Functions for fetching data and moving to the content screen are as follows:

```py
def load_content(self, query):
    req_body = json.dumps({'content': query})
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    req = UrlRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5000/recipes/ask_mobile', self.got_json, req_body=req_body,
                        req_headers=headers)

def content_screen(self, result):
    self.root.current = 'content_screen'
    content_screen = self.root.get_screen('content_screen')
    content_screen.ids.content_label.text = result
    print(result)

def got_json(self, req, result):
    for key, value in req.resp_headers.items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
    recipe = result['data']
    print(recipe)
    self.content_screen(recipe)
```

This is what I have at the moment

[image]

So we load content which triggers gotJson and then move to the content screen, which places the response in the text of the label. I hope that all makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The Label that holds the content must be under the ScrollView.  The size of the Scrolling item must be fixed (not hinted).  Here is a small example:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Label in a ScrollView'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(30)
    ScrollView:
        Label:                # the widget to scroll is UNDER the scrollview
            id: content
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint_y: None               # the size must be fixed - not hinted to scroll
            height: self.texture_size[1]

"""

class ScrollingLabelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.content.text = 'Some long, long, amount of text to demo scrolling. ' * 200

ScrollingLabelApp().run()
```